# Frame of reference to measure velocity for relativistic momentum

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, momentum, inertial-frames

I have a general question about the relativistic momentum equation. The same question could be asked about the relativistic kinetic energy.

What reference frame is used to measure the velocity, $v=\frac{distance}{time}$?

$$\mathbf{p}=\frac{mv}{\root{2}\of{1-\frac{v^{2}}{c^{2}}}}$$

Suppose the momentum of an electron is being observed in a lab. It could be observed in a lab that as the speed of electron increases, it becomes harder to accelerate it. To measure the velocity of electron, we need to measure distance or displacement and time.

Practically, IMHO, both of these quantities would be measured in lab's frame of reference. I don't see any other way to do it. Do I have it correct? Could you please help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This equation is based on inertial frames. So it can be measured in any inertial frame. Assuming that the lab is inertial then that includes the lab frame and any frame moving uniformly with respect to the lab frame.

Comment: Thank you! So, if in a lab frame, one would be using his own time and distance measurement to calculate momentum of electron, then to get the correct expression for relativistic momentum, one has to take into account the fact that mass gets difficult to accelerate as the speed increases. Wouldn't this to lead to the idea of relativistic mass?

Comment: PG1995 No doubt it *did* lead, unfortunately, to the idea of relativistic mass, but this concept is now viewed as unnecessary (duplicating the concept of total energy) and confusing. Instead, think of the gamma factor as making the *momentum* increase more steeply with $v$ than $v$ itself increases.